# Suppressing errors messages that might occur when using cat command with EOF or EOD in bash script

Tags: bash

My aim is to suppress all the error messages that might occur when using `cat` with `EOF` or `EOD`.

When I run the bash script, I'm getting error below because I deliberately added `/` sign at the end of the file name.

ERROR

```
my-hello.sh: line 5: hello.txt/: Is a directory
BAD
```

SCRIPT

```
#!/bin/bash

function create()
{
    cat << EOF > hello.txt/
    Hello
EOF
}

createHook
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   printf "GOOD"
else
   printf "BAD"
fi
```

How can I suppress error message being printed on the terminal?

I tried `2>/dev/null` so on but `EOF` doesn't like it because of known white spacing reasons.

NOTE: The content of the file is actually bigger but I've just put `Hello` in it simplify. I'm open for changes if that solves my problem.

Comment: `cat` has nothing whatsoever to do with this error, nor does your use of a herestring (`EOF`/`EOD`). `echo >hello.txt/` would behave exactly the same way, as would `ls >hello.txt/`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use redirection to `/dev/null` like this:

```
function create()
{

    cat 2>/dev/null << EOF > hello.txt/
    Hello
EOF
}
```

You can also redirect all the errors from the `create()` function:

```
function create()
{
    cat << EOF > hello.txt/
    Hello
EOF
}

createHook 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Please consider encouraging POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax -- that is, `create() {` with no preceding `function`. `function create() {` is nonportable to other shells, but has no compensating advantages over the compliant syntax.

Comment: Looks like I used `2>/dev/null` wrong places! Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you mean I should get rid of `function` keyword?

Comment: @BentCoder, yes. Using `function` means your code isn't guaranteed to work with `#!/bin/sh`, but unlike other bashisms that have advantages associated, `function` has no upsides to compensate for this loss of portability.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the info. I'll do that.